# ReactJS and Less, set dynamic class

Tags: reactjs, less

I have a component like this:

```
import '../MLExtraIcon.less';

const MLExtraIcon = ({ text, color }) => (
  <span className={`ml-extra-icon ml-extra-icon-color-${color}`}>
    {text}
  </span>
);
```

So, I call `<MLExtraIcon>` components with 2 props: text and color

But currenly, I have hardcoded the "color" as a class in a less file which is:

```
// MLExtraIcon.less
@import "../colors";

.ml-extra-icon {
    &.ml-extra-icon-color-passion {
        background-color: @passion;
    }
}
```

And in the imported `colors` file I have a bunch of variables like:

```
// colors.less
@opportunities: #F47521;
@innovation: #1976BD;
@passion: #CB198A;
// etc...
```

How could I select dynamically the variable to use in the .less file? I mean, my problem is here:

```
.ml-extra-icon {
    &.ml-extra-icon-color-passion {. <--- that's hardcoded, I would like to know if
        background-color: @passion;
    }
}
```

...if there's a way to give the variable name as a parameter, for instance:

```
.ml-extra-icon {
    &.ml-extra-icon-color-$color {
        background-color: $color;
    }
}
```

(I'm inventing that syntax, in order to explain what I want to achieve). I don't want to create different css clases for each already declared less variable (like the hardcoded example)

Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it dynamic you can use `styled-components`. Example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-architecture-j070x)

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {

  const ColorWrapper = styled.span`
    color: ${(props) => props.color};
  `;

  const MLExtraIcon = ({ text, color }) => (
    <ColorWrapper color={color}>{text}</ColorWrapper>
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {MLExtraIcon({ text: "Your passion", color: "blue" })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also you can create global `theme` file instead of local `const theme`, to use it throughout the project.

Comment: That's what I commented, that I don't want to create each class for each less variable, because the file that contains variables are maintained somewhere else

Comment: @pmiranda, I edited answer

Comment: ok, thanks, that would change all, and I'll have to hardcode the colors values too, but I think I will end using different css clases per less variable.

Comment: @pmiranda, I edited answer, you can do it without  hardcode the colors.